# Install a command line only Linux in Virtual Box in Windows and access Windows home directory from there

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, network-shares

I want to have a command only linux installed in Virtual Box and access my Windows home directory (User directory) from there to enjoy powerful linux commands and easier SSH to my remote machines and so on.

- What version of Linux is the best option for this case? Consider that
  I'm running this on a laptop computer and battery usage is important.
- How can I share my home folder with the virtual Linux machine in VM?
- Is it possible to map`~` to that shared folder?

I've already tried Cygwin and Putty. I think this would be much better Linux if I could accomplish it.

Comment: That kinda defeats the purpose of a virtual machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ekaj said, a VM is not the best way to go about this. Why not use the following instead?

- [GNU utilities for Win32](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/): Ports of common GNU utilities to native Win32 (native means the executables depend only on the Microsoft C-runtime (msvcrt.dll) and not an emulation layer like that provided by Cygwin).
- [GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/): Ports of tools with a GNU or similar open source license, to modern MS-Windows (Microsoft Windows 2000/XP/2003/Vista/2008/7).

There are also "C Shell" programs available for Windows that you can check out (the author of one of them is a member here), but the ones I've come across are not free/open source.

Comment: I would add [GOW](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) as an option, its a pretty nice packaged set of *nix style utilities. It dosen't have anything the other two don't, but its the simplest to install and get running